# How to inject servletcontext for junit test cases which are autowired in source controller

Tags: java, spring, servlets, junit

I have a controller class in which, servletContext is autowired.

```
@Controller
public class BaseController {
    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

protected ServletContext getServletContext() {
        return servletContext;
    }

    public Object getBean(String beanName) {

        ApplicationContext appContext =    WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(this.servletContext);
        return appContext.getBean(beanName);
    }
}
```

The `getBean()` in `BaseController` is used by many methods in subclasses extending it.

When I tried to execute jUnit test cases for the methods in subclasses (which were invoking `getBean()`), I was getting the below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ServletContext must not be null
```

I am unable to load web.xml while running junit.

Can someone please help in explaining , on how to set servlet context from JUnit ? If `MockServletContext` is the solution, please provide a code snippet on how to inject `MockServletContext`, to the autowired servletContext in the controller.

**Note :** There is no `setServletContext()` in `BaseController`

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but you should not use the ApplicationContext in a controller. Instead just inject the beans into your controller.

Comment: @stefan Birkner : I agree. I should not be using ApplicationContext in the controller. But it is an exisiting source code which should not be modified now due to project constraints. But the issue is servletcontext is coming as null, while running a jUnit test case. So please let me know the step to inject servletcontext from junit.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the servletContext with PowerMock's [WhiteBox](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/blob/master/reflect/src/main/java/org/powermock/reflect/Whitebox.java).

```
WhiteBox.setInternalState(controller, "servletContext", yourServletContext);
```

Comment: Above approach works only for static field. But as shown in the above code, servletContext is a private non-static field. So please suggest a way to inject servletContext from jUnit , where servletContext in Source file is @Autowired private field

Comment: It works with non-static fields. (That's the reason why the first parameter is an object.) Why do you think that it does only work with static fields?